# How to create a drop down Time Selection

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a TimeBox like Google Calendar's From time with Google Apps Script, but there is no `createTimeBox` method, what should I do?

use `createDateBox()` method I could create an expanding Calendar Selection, but I don't know how to create a drop down Time Selection.

I haven't found the `UiApp`  method about create drop down time selection the same as Google Calendar's From time

Comment: do you want 1/2 hour resolution like in google Cal ? or more ? or less ?

Comment: Yes, The same as google Cal 1/2 hour. Could you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom list box of hours, list box of minutes and a choice between am / pm.  Assuming you'll want to do some thing further with the date + time you'll need to convert the number of hours and minutes into milliseconds and add them into the date.getTime().

[Demo](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyafW6rMMXhXVJgEvqNR3P_riVNg2oLNfSU12IWKuwCN49EuWdW/exec)

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var hpanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  var dateBox = app.createDateBox().setId('dateBox').setName('dateBox');
  var hour = app.createListBox(false).setId('hour').setName('hour')
  .addItem(1).addItem(2).addItem(3);  // ADD ALL THE HOURS YOU WANT

  var min = app.createListBox(false).setId('minute').setName('minute')
  .addItem('00').addItem('15').addItem('30').addItem('45');  // ADD ALL THE MINUTES YOU WANT

  var amPm = app.createListBox(false).setId('am').setName('amPm')
  .addItem('AM').addItem('PM');  

  var dateTimeLabel = app.createLabel('',false).setId('dateTimeLabel');
  var submit = app.createButton('Submit').setId('submit');

  // SUBMIT HANDLERS
  var handler1 = app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setEnabled(false);
  var handler2 = app.createServerHandler('showDate').addCallbackElement(hpanel);
  submit.addClickHandler(handler1).addClickHandler(handler2);

  hpanel.add(dateBox).add(hour).add(min).add(amPm).add(submit).add(dateTimeLabel);
  app.add(hpanel);
  return app;
}

function showDate(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var date = e.parameter.dateBox;
  var timeZone = date.toString().substr(25,6)+":00";  // SCRIPT TIME ZONE
  var dateMilli = date.getTime();  // GET MILLISECONDS OF DATE PICKED
  var hour = parseInt(e.parameter.hour);  // TURN INTO NUMBER
  var amPm = e.parameter.amPm;
  if (amPm == 'PM' && hour != 12) hour = hour + 12;  // ADD 12 HOURS TO PM HOURS, EXCEPT 12PM
  if (hour == 12 && amPm == 'AM') hour = 0;  // HANDLE 12AM HOUR CORRECTLY
  var hourMilli = hour * 3600000;  // # OF MILLISECONDS IN 1 HOUR 
  var minMilli = parseInt(e.parameter.minute) * 60000;  // # OF MILLISECONDS IN 1 MIN
  var milliTotal = dateMilli + hourMilli + minMilli; // ADD ALL MILLISECOND TOGETHER

  // PUT TOTAL MILLISECONDS INTO A NEW DATE AND CREATE CUSTOM FORMAT
  // THIS MIGHT NOT BE THE USER'S BROWSER TIME ZONE 
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(milliTotal), timeZone, 'MM/dd/yy hh:mm aaa');
  app.getElementById('dateTimeLabel').setText(newDate);
  app.getElementById('submit').setEnabled(true);
  return app;
}
```

If you need to display the date + time back to the user in their browser time zone - you'll need to know their what that is ahead of time and set it in the Script Properties.  Unless there's a way to automatically adjust the script time zone programatically...?

Comment: there seems to be a small issue in this code : if you choose 00:15AM it becomes 12:15 AM in the dateTimeLabel.  Also you should add a validator on both handlers to prevent error when no date is selected.

Comment: I was thinking for a second that the date going in was attached to the browser tz, but that's not the case.  We still can't run this and display the date back as the user's browser tz without knowing it ahead of time, right? (even when it's being ran as user accessing)

Comment: Thanks! But I need the same as Google Calendar's From time.

Comment: You'll need to just combine hours/min/amPm into 1 list box then.

Comment: How could I do, Could you give me some examples, Thanks!

Comment: +BryanP: With you method I couldn't input time which I don't want the list time.e.g.8:15.

Answer (score 0):

here is a variant of Bryan's script with one or two small improvements to handle case hour=0 and a validator on the dateBox to prevent throwing error if no date is selected.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var hpanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  var dateBox = app.createDateBox().setId('dateBox').setName('dateBox');
  var hour = app.createListBox(false).setId('hour').setName('hour')
  for(h=0;h<13;++h){hour.addItem(h)}

  var min = app.createListBox(false).setId('minute').setName('minute')
  .addItem('00').addItem('15').addItem('30').addItem('45');  // ADD ALL THE MINUTES YOU WANT

  var amPm = app.createListBox(false).setId('am').setName('amPm')
  .addItem('AM').addItem('PM');

  var dateTimeLabel = app.createLabel('',false).setId('dateTimeLabel');
  var submit = app.createButton('Submit').setId('submit');

  // SUBMIT HANDLERS
  var handler1 = app.createClientHandler().validateMatches(dateBox, '2','g').forEventSource().setEnabled(false);
  var handler2 = app.createServerHandler('showDate').validateMatches(dateBox, '2','g').addCallbackElement(hpanel);
  submit.addClickHandler(handler1).addClickHandler(handler2);

  hpanel.add(dateBox).add(hour).add(min).add(amPm).add(submit);
  app.add(hpanel).add(dateTimeLabel);
  return app;
}

function showDate(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var date = e.parameter.dateBox;
  var timeZone = date.toString().substr(25,6)+":00";  // timezone of this date according to script TZ
  var hour = Number(e.parameter.hour);  // TURN INTO NUMBER
  var min = Number(e.parameter.minute); // TURN INTO NUMBER
  var amPm = e.parameter.amPm;
  if (amPm == 'PM' ){hour = hour+12};  // ADD 12 HOURS TO PM HOURS
  if (hour == 24){hour = 0 ;amPm='AM'};  // HANDLE 24 HOUR CORRECTLY
  var newDate=new Date(date)
  newDate.setHours(hour,min,0,0);//set hours minutes sec and milliSecs
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(newDate, timeZone, 'MM/dd/yy hh:mm aaa');
  app.getElementById('dateTimeLabel').setText(newDate);
  app.getElementById('submit').setEnabled(true);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I need the same as Google Calendar's From time. How could I do?

Comment: Do you mean with hours and minutes in the same select box with half hours presets ?

Comment: Yes. and list 1/2 hour like Google Calendar.